# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: support

Why was Travis Parks' answer deleted on the [Multi-tiered sorting using custom IComparer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12221/multi-tiered-sorting-using-custom-icomparer) question? Is there a place on the site where we can see the reason of a delete?

Comment: If you want information on the action of moderators, asking on meta is the right place. I wasn't the moderator who did that, so you'll have to wait for them answer.

Comment: If you check the revision history, you can see it was deleted (comment converted actually) before the answer was expanded. Revision history tracks when a post was deleted relative to revisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time I deleted the answer, it was:

> As the creator of NList, I can confirm that @palacsint's solution is how NList is implemented internally.

It received a low quality flag, and I felt it would be better as a comment. I converted it to a [comment on your answer.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12221/multi-tiered-sorting-using-custom-icomparer#comment20231_12273)

I see that he's expanded it into a better answer, so I've undeleted it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: As a note; if you've improved a deleted answer such that it should be undeleted, flag it for moderator attention; you can't manually undelete posts deleted by moderator action